# How can I integrate 'scale2ref' to scale a watermark while preserving its display aspect ratio, into this line of code

Tags: ffmpeg, php

The ffmpeg documentation shows:

> Scale a logo to 1/10th the height of a video, while preserving its display aspect ratio:

```
[logo-in][video-in]scale2ref=w=oh*mdar:h=ih/10[logo-out][video-out]
```

I need guidance with integrating scale2ref into a current line of code, for example:

```
$ffmpegCommand =''.$ffmpeg_b.' -y -i '.$video_file_full_path.' -i '.escapeshellarg($watermark_image_full_path).' -i '.escapeshellarg($watermark_image_full_path).' -filter_complex "scale=426:-2, scale=426:-2, overlay=10:10, overlay=170:170:enable=between(t\,5\,5+2)" -vcodec libx264 -preset '.$pt->config->convert_speed.' -crf 26 '.$video_output_full_path_240.' 2>&1';
```

any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: You have two watermark inputs (the same one!), how much do you wish to resize them?

Comment: Thank you Gyan for your message. Yes, I do have two which are the same watermarks.The web video script that I’m using adds the watermarks successfully, however, the watermark.png looks ok on the small screen, but in 'full screen' the watermark.png image looks much less sharp, blurry/pixelated.

‘scale2ref’ seems like a possible solution. I have tried different attempts with it without success. The ffmpeg documentation shows:

“Scale a logo to 1/10th the height of a video, while preserving its display aspect ratio”. I m looking for help to integrate 'scale2ref' to preserve the aspect ratio